# Schedule airflow job bi-weekly

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a requirement that I want to schedule an airflow job every alternate Friday. However, the problem is I am not able to figure out how to write a schedule for this.

I don't want to have multiple jobs for this.

I tried this

```
'0 0 1-7,15-21 * 5
```

However it's not working it's running from 1 to 7 and 15 to 21 everyday.

from shubham's answer I realize that we can have a PythonOperator which can skip the task for us. An I tried to implement the solution. However doesn't seem to work.

As testing this on 2 week period would be too difficult. This is what I did.

- I schedule the DAG to run every 5 mins
- However, I am writing python operator the skip althernate task (pretty similar to what I am trying to do, alternate friday).

**DAG:**

```py
args = {
    'owner': 'Gaurang Shah',
    'retries': 0,
    'start_date':airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),
}


dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test_dag',
    default_args=args,
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *',
    max_active_runs=1
    )


dummy_op = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy', dag=dag)

def _check_date(execution_date, **context):
    min_date = datetime.now() - relativedelta(minutes=10)
    print(context)
    print(context.get("prev_execution_date"))
    print(execution_date)
    print(datetime.now())
    print(min_date)
    if execution_date > min_date:
        raise AirflowSkipException(f"No data available on this execution_date ({execution_date}).")

check_date = PythonOperator(
    task_id="check_if_min_date",
    python_callable=_check_date,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- I doubt that a single `crontab` expression [can solve this](https://www.google.com/search?q=crontab+every+alternate+friday)
- Using `airflow`'s tricks, solution is much more straightforward:

  - schedule your DAG every Friday [`0 0 * * FRI`](https://crontab.guru/every-friday) and
  - on alternate Fridays (based on your business logic), skip the DAG by raising [`AirflowSkipException`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62931983/3679900)

  Here you'll have to let your DAG begin with a dedicated `skip_decider` task that will let your DAG run / skip every alternate Friday by

  - conditionally raising `AirflowSkipException` (to skip the DAG)
  - not doing anything to let the DAG run

---

You can also leverage

- [`ShortCircuitOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python_operator/index.html#airflow.operators.python_operator.ShortCircuitOperator)
- [`BranchPythonOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python_operator/index.html#airflow.operators.python_operator.BranchPythonOperator)

but IMO, `AirflowSkipException` is the cleanest solution

---

Reference: [How to define a DAG that scheduler a monthly job together with a daily job?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57104547/3679900)

Comment: seems like a good alternate.. could you please elborate how to skip the second run  ?

Comment: **@Gaurang Shah** check [point 4 'Skipping execution of tasks'](https://godatadriven.com/blog/the-zen-of-python-and-apache-airflow/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I gone through the post, however I am not able to understand the logic. `execution_date > (datetime.datetime.now() - relativedelta(weeks=1))`  wouldn't `exceution_date` and `dateime.datetime.now` be same. I tested this and both comes same.

Comment: **@Gaurang Shah** Read the section titled [What is the difference between execution_date and start_date?](https://towardsdatascience.com/airflow-schedule-interval-101-bbdda31cc463)

Comment: @Thanks for the post. I understand the different. in my case both shows same with only 5-10 seconds difference. I created a dag which triggers at 5 min.. and I was skipping task if duration is less than 10 mins.. however it's not working.. may be I will open a new question or update here

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your  implementation you can use the hash. Worked in my airflow schedules using version 1.10:

Hash (#)
'#' is allowed for the day-of-week field, and must be followed by a number between one and five. It allows specifying constructs such as "the second Friday" of a given month.[19] For example, entering "5#3" in the day-of-week field corresponds to the third Friday of every month. [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Answer (score -2):

you can use timedelta as mentioned below, combine it with start_date to schedule your job bi_weekly.

```
   dag = DAG(
       dag_id='test_dag',
       default_args=args,
       catchup=False,
       start_date=datetime(2021, 3, 26),
       schedule_interval=timedelta(days=14),
       max_active_runs=1
   )
```

Comment: this can't work as not every month as same number of days.